# Unable to scroll second para using animation in css

Tags: html, css

I have tried scroll second para using animation but unable to scroll. I have used p as inline-block but it's overriding the data. I want to scroll one para after second one and so on.
I have attached the below code.

```css
.marquee {
            height: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background: #fefefe;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
        }
        
        .marquee p {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
            -moz-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
            -webkit-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
            animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
        }
        
        @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
        <p> 1Marquee in CSS </p> <p> 2Marquee in CSS </p> <p>3 Marquee in CSS </p>
    </div>
```

Could you please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you'd be better off giving the paragraphs their own container and animating that.

The issue is that as soon as you give the marquee paragraphs a position of absolute, they all collect to top left by default.

```css
.marquee {
            height: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background: #fefefe;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
        }
        
.marquee p {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;    
}

.marquee__content{
    
            -moz-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
            -webkit-animation: scroll-left 2s linear infinite;
            animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
}
        
        @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes scroll-left {
            0% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
                transform: translateX(100%);
            }
            100% {
                -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
                -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
                transform: translateX(-100%);
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
    <div class="marquee__content">
        <p> 1Marquee in CSS </p> <p> 2Marquee in CSS </p> <p>3 Marquee in CSS </p>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I used more content but half content only scrolling could you please help. below is the data (  <p>1 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
        <p>2 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
        <p>3 It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
  )

Comment: could you help for large text